# SQL bulk copy for native clients causes access violation

Tags: c++, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have a windows application that does a bulk copy of data to an SQL table, using the `bcp_xxx()` functions and a standard "SQL Server" ODBC connector.

I want to move to supporting native SQL client connections

According to what I have seen, all I need to do is add

```
#define _SQLNCLI_ODBC_
#include <sqlncli.h>
```

to the top of the cpp file, and link against "sqlncli10.lib" rather than "odbcbcp.lib."

However, when I call `bcp_bind()`, I get "`Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff`"
This happens with both "SQL server" and "SQL Native Client" ODBC connections.

The code being executed is:

```
SQLHANDLE hEnv;
SQLHANDLE hConnection;
LPCBYTE data = (LPCBYTE)malloc(100);

SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hConnection);
SQLSetConnectAttr(hConnection, SQL_COPT_SS_BCP, (void *)SQL_BCP_ON, SQL_IS_INTEGER) ;
SQLConnect(hConnection, "DSN", SQL_NTSL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
bcp_init(hConnection, "DB_TABLE", NULL, NULL, DB_IN);
bcp_bind(hConnection, data, 0, SQL_VARLEN_DATA, (LPCBYTE)"", 1, SQLCHARACTER, 1);
```

Comment: You need to post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information. Two lines of code fails the "Complete" requirements, and posting your entire application would obviously fail the "Minimal" part. You need to post the shortest test code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be due to using "SQL server" ODBC connections at the same time as the bulk copy routines are trying to use native connections.

If I change all other ODBC connections to be SQL Native, the bulk copy routines work correctly.